# How use Gridfs of mongodb with PIL (Python Image Library)

Tags: python, mongodb, python-imaging-library, gridfs

i use mongodb and save file to gridfs

now i want edit images from gridfs ...

i use this code

```
def thumbnail(file_obj):
    import StringIO
    from PIL import Image

    im = StringIO.StringIO()

    im.write(file_obj.raw_file)

    im_ful = Image.open(im)

    return im_ful.info
```

but pil said "cannot identify image file"

thats image also ;) 
how can fix it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an `im.seek(0)` before the `Image.open(im)` call. Otherwise PIL tries to read from the end of the file, gets no data, and fails.